# How to do object construction for a class that uses the init syntax?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

```
public class Person
{
   private string _myName;

   public Person(string myName)
   {
      _myName= myName;
   }

   public string Name => _myName;
}
```

My understanding of object construction use is like this: `var obj = new Person("Tim");`

An init-only setter assigns a value to the property or the indexer element only during object construction. Following is sample code using `init`:

```
public class Person
{
   private string _myName;

   public string Name
     {
         get => _myName; 
         init => _myName= value;
     }
}
```

What is the way to construct an object for such a class so that the init is invoked during object construction? For example, it is:

1. `var obj = new Person("Tim");`
2. `var obj = new Person().Name("Tim");`
3. `var obj = new Person(); obj.Name="Tim";`

I cannot find how object is created in `init` examples from this msdn link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/init

Comment: It's `var obj = new Person() { Name = "Tim" };` just like with normal get/set properties.

Comment: `new Person() { Name = "Tim" }` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/init

Comment: @JL0PD - that link doesn't mention this.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers

Comment: Can this help you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your class `Person` doesn't expose a parameterless constructor, the only constructor your class has is one that takes a string as a parameter, meaning you cannot call `new Person();` you **must** supply a parameter of type string. Meaning, the only way to create a new `Person` in you current example is:

```
var person = new Person("Anders Hejlsberg");
```

And after that you cannot modify `Name` as the initialisation of the object is complete. If you want to *change* the `Name` property later, you'll have to remove the `init` keyword and use a normal setter. If you want to initialize your object like

```cs
var person = new Person
{
    Name = "Denis Ritchie"
};
```

(Side note: This is because `new Person { ... }` implicitly calls a parameterless constructor, i.e it's equal to `new Person() { ... }`, you could also do `new Person("Richard Stallman") { ... }` if you wanted to enforce that a Person must always have a `Name`)

You'll have to give your class a parameterless constructor (or remove your one and only constructor), I'd also recommend using an [auto property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) (i.e no explicit backing field). Re-writing your class like so would result in this:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
}

// usage
var person = new Person
{
    Name = "Erich Gamma"
};
```

---

If you want to enforce that object of type `Person` always have a `Name` set, but still want to use `init` properties for other properties, you can do that like so:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; init; }

    public string Nickname { get; init; }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

// usage
var linus1 = new Person("Linus Torvalds");
var linus2 = new Person("Linus Sebastian")
{
    Nickname = "Linus 'TechTips' Sebastian"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It would simply be

```cs
var myPerson = new Person() { Name = "Tim" };
```

or, you can even omit the parenthesis, this would be valid.

```cs
var myPerson = new Person { Name = "Tim" };
```

Also, you can greatly simplify your example, you don't need to define the attribute `myName`. You can simply use the auto-properties like that:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
}
```